# How to set the first option on a select box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two HTML `select` boxes. I need to reset one `select` box when I make a selection in another.

```
<select id="name" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select id="name2" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

When I select an option of the first `select` (i.e. `id="name"`), I need to reset the second `select` to `select all`; similarly, when I select an option of the second `select` (i.e. `id="name2"`), I need to reset the first `select` to `select all`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I changed the title from _[...]reset[...]_ to _[...]set the first option on[...]_ because _reset_ implies setting the default initially loaded value

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/898/

```
$('#name2').change(function(){
    $('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});


$('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

Comment: True, but it still shows the basic concept, and in this case it looks like he wants to reset it to "Select All", which is the first option.

Comment: If you use this from a `<button>` element, be sure to do not set `type="reset"`. It didn't work for me until I set type to `button`

Comment: I does select the first element of the dropdown but the text is still the old one.

Comment: I am using this as a rest of select box is it ok? or am I not getting it properly?

Comment: @ankitsuthar It will change the selected option of the `select` to the value provided. `select.prop('selectedIndex', 0)` will reset it the first option, `select.prop('selectedIndex', 1)` will set it to the second option.

Comment: @Jack not in my case, I had to use ````select.prop('selectedIndex', 1)```` to set my first index. I dont know why

Answer (score 45):

If you just want to reset the select element to it's first position, the simplest way may be:

```
$('#name2').val('');
```

To reset all select elements in the document:

```
$('select').val('')
```

EDIT: To clarify as per a comment below, this resets the select element to its first blank entry and only if a blank entry exists in the list.

Comment: Yeah this would work almost all the time. Other solutions may sometimes have issues.
Simplest way indeed.

Comment: Just a warning: this will only work if you indeed want to have the first option selected and the first option has a value set of blank. If your first option has some other value or if no option in the SELECT box has a value of blank, then this won't affect any change. Or, if some other option has a value of blank, it will select that option instead.

Comment: @HBlackorby, your comment was helpful, but 1) The option with `value=""` can appear in any order. 2) An option **without** a value attribute i.e. `<option></option>` is not the same as an option with an empty-string value attribute i.e. `<option value=""></option>`, and you made it clear we need the `value=""` [part](https://jsfiddle.net/theredpea/zpwtjw5z/1/) 3) Even if there are no `<option>` with empty-string value; setting `.val('')` will "affect change", the select will appear to change to blank, isn't that right? [At least in my Chrome...](https://jsfiddle.net/theredpea/zpwtjw5z/1/)

Answer (score 24):

As pointed out by @PierredeLESPINAY in the comments, my original solution was incorrect - it would reset the dropdown to the topmost option, but only because the `undefined` return value resolved to index 0.

Here's a correct solution, which takes the `selected` property into account:

```
$('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').val(function () {
        return $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
            return $(this).prop('defaultSelected');
        }).val();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/weg82/257/](http://jsfiddle.net/weg82/257/)

---

**Original answer - INCORRECT**

In jQuery 1.6+ you need to use the [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to get the default selection:

```
// Resets the name2 dropdown to its default value
$('#name2').val( $('#name2').prop('defaultSelected') );
```

To make it reset dynamically when the first dropdown changes, use the [`.change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$('#name').change(function(){
  $('#name2').val( $('#name2').prop('defaultSelected') );
});
```

Comment: what Jens Roland said, with the viceversa support ^^ http://jsfiddle.net/weg82/2/

Comment: But vice versa support doesn't make sense-- That is equivalent to one large dropdown. I don't get it.

Comment: it's suffice to just write `$('#name2').val( $(this).prop('defaultSelected') );`

Comment: @vsync: `$(this)` refers to `$('#name')`, not `$('#name2')`, so no

Comment: `defaultSelected` is an `<option>` property, will always return `undefined` on a `<select>`

Answer (score 7):

Use this if you want to reset the select to the option which has the "selected" attribute. Works similar to the form.reset() inbuilt javascript function to the select.

```
 $("#name").val($("#name option[selected]").val());
```

Answer (score 4):

This helps me a lot.

```
$(yourSelector).find('select option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it to work if you just want to get it back to your first option e.g. "Choose an option"
"Select_id_wrap" is obviously the div around the select, but I just want to make that clear just in case it has any bearing on how this works.  Mine resets to a click function but I'm sure it will work inside of an on change as well...

```
$("#select_id_wrap").find("select option").prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below. See it working here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/3HPz4/

```
 $(function(){
     $('#name').change(function(){
         $('#name2 option[value=""]').attr('selected','selected');
     });

     $('#name2').change(function(){
         $('#name option[value=""]').attr('selected','selected');
     });
 });
```

Comment: Again - only works if the default is fixed as the first/empty one

Answer (score 3):

This can also be used

```
$('#name2').change(function(){
    $('#name').val('');//You can set the first value of first one if that is not empty
});


$('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most flexible/reusable way to reset all select boxes in your form.

```
      var $form = $('form') // Replace with your form selector
      $('select', $form).each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultSelected'));
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting option 1 in the select element can be done by this segment. To visually show it, you have tp add .trigger('change') at the end.

```
$('#name').removeAttr('selected').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to handle it with a random option element defined as the default value (in this case Text 2 is the default):

```
<select id="name2" >
   <option value="">select all</option>
   <option value="1">Text 1</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Text 2</option>
   <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('#name2 option[selected]').prop('selected', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$( 'select' ).each( function () {
    if ( $( this ).children().length > 0 ) {
        $( $( this ).children()[0] ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
        $( this ).change();
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem using the defaultSelected property in the answer by @Jens Roland in jQuery v1.9.1. A more generic way (with many dependent selects) would be to put a data-default attribute in your dependent selects and then iterate through them when reseting.

```
<select id="name0" >
    <option value="">reset</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select id="name1" class="name" data-default="1">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1" selected="true">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select id="name2" class="name" data-default="2">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="true">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

And the javascript...

```
$('#name0').change(function(){
    if($('#name0').val() == '') {
        $('select.name').each(function(index){
          $(this).val($(this).data('default'))  
        })
    } else {
      $('select.name').val($('#name0').val() );
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8hvqN/ for a working version of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new option in the select tag that has a value of empty string ("") and used:

```
$("form.query").find('select#topic').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for binding onchange event to select but you don't need to create another `$(this)` jquery object.

```
$('select[name=name2]').change(function(){
    if (this.value) {
        console.log('option value = ', this.value);
        console.log('option text  = ', this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);

        // Reset selected
        this.selectedIndex = this.defaultSelected;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to reset all selection fields to the default option, where the attribute selected is defined.

```
<select id="name1" >
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" >Default Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name2" >
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected" >Default Text 3</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('select').each( function() {
        $(this).val( $(this).find("option[selected]").val() );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution im using. This will apply for over 1 slectbox

```js
$("select").change(function(){
    var thisval = $(this).val();
    $("select").prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $(this).val(thisval);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#name').prop('selectedIndex', 0), 
$('#name').attr('selected', 'selected'), 
$('#name').find('select option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true), 
$("#name option[value=none]")
```

All of those options would work only if you add .change() to it to update your dropdown to show the first option.