# clear the value in select form element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to clear/empty the selected value in an select element in a jQuery application

```
<div  data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select style="font-weight: normal" name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

using the following line

```
$('#select-choice-1').val('');
```

However it does not clear. The selected value remains intact.

http://jsfiddle.net/neilghosh/MECXW/11/

Comment: it seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445492/how-to-reset-select-box-using-jquery

Comment: not a duplicate, as the OP doesn't have a placeholder value for "select one" at the top.

Answer (score 1):

A single-valued `select` *always* has a selected value, which will default to the first entry.

If you want an "empty" option, you need to add it to the top of the list of options yourself, and then exclude it if it's actually used.

Answer (score 0):

val() is more like a shortcut for attr('value'). For your usage use text() or html() instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(){
                $('select option:first').attr('selected','selected');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<select>
<option value="0">--select--</select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button>Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the OP only wants to deselect the value, not remove it from the list.

Comment: @Alnitak this code will make it to the default option (--select-- in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery Mobile. So you need to refresh your component:

Check this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guumaster/MECXW/15/ (*)

Basically you have to "refresh" it like this:

```
    $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Check the [jQuery Mobile docs for Selects](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)     ​

(*) I've also added an option without value called "None".