# Clear only specific fields in HTML form when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following HTML form code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="-add" data-theme="c" class="ui-corner-all" data-dismissible="false" data-overlay-theme="a" style="min-width:550px;">
    <div data-role="content"> <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" style="position:absolute;top:-20px;right:-15px;">Delete</a>

        <form id="item-form" action="#" formaction="process" data-ajax="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="hidden1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="how" value="hidden2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="hidden3" />
            <input type="hidden" name="itemtype" value="hidden4" />
            <div align="left">
                 <h3> Add</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="popup-hrule"></div>
            <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <label for="location_name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="location_name" id="location_name" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" data-schema="types">
                    <label for="type_name">Type</label>
                    <select name="type_name" id="type_name">
                        <option data-item=".textarea:name; .value:id; .repeat:true"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <label for="state">State</label>
                    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <label for="zip">Postal</label>
                    <input type="number" name="zip" id="zip" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <label for="_lat">Latitude</label>
                    <input type="number" name="_lat" id="_lat" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <label for="_lon">Longitude</label>
                    <input type="number" name="_lon" id="_lon" value="">
                </div>
            </div> <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close');">Cancel</a>
 <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();$(this).closest('form').find('input').val('');$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close')">Add</a>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since this is an ADD form I would like to close the form and clear all the fields except for the hidden ones at the top which are flags that tell me what I have to do with the data. When I execute the code it clears all the data in the form including the hidden fields so the second time I can't add a new record.

A best approach for me would be to close the form completely so I don't have to erase the fields in the form which are going to get new data when I try to open it again.

Comment: Do you want to clear all input fields except the hidden inputs?

Comment: A bit confused on what your trying to accomplish... are you trying to POST the form and keep the values... so that you can POST it again?

Comment: @JordanDavis No, I want to POST the form and clear the values except for the hidden values.

Comment: @SaulOrtega ahh okay got it now... use David's answer will work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A best approach for me would be to close the form completely so I
>   don't have to erase the fields in the form which are going to get new
>   data when I try to open it again.

```
$("#item-form").remove();
```

If the hidden fields are populated from server, you can reset the form, so all form fields will be reset to value which were there during page reload.

```
 $('#item-form')[0].reset();
```

The plain JS way of doing it

```
document.getElementById("item-form").reset();
```

Updated after discussion with OP

```
<a href="javascript:resetForm()">Cancel</a>

function resetForm() { 
   $('#item-form')[0].reset(); 
   $(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup(‌​'close'); 
}
```

Comment: #item-form would be the id of the popup or the form?

Comment: Its the id of the form.

Comment: I did this `<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="$('item-form').remove();">Cancel</a>` and the button doesn't do anything when I click on it. Did I miss something?

Comment: @SaulOrtega: Yes, you missed the `#` in the selector.  That jQuery selector is looking for an `<item-form />` element, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep # is missed :)  `$('#item-form').remove();`

Comment: This is what I see when I click the Close button: http://s30.postimg.org/csph4liwx/image.png

Comment: @SaulOrtega thats because the form element is removed from your popup. Close the popup after you remove the form.

Comment: Right, so that's why I was wondering if I had to do it do the whole popup, because I would like to reset the popup and then when I click to open the popup populate it back.

Comment: @SaulOrtega In that case you need to reset the form using `$('#item-form')[0].reset();` and close the popup after that.

Comment: `onclick="$('#item-form')[0].reset();$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close');">Cancel</a>` Yes, exactly what I thought. Thanks man!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87912/discussion-between-kiranvj-and-saul-ortega).

Answer (score 2):

You're clearing *all* `input` elements:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input').val('');
```

If you want to clear only some of them, you need to target specifically the ones you want.  For example, if you want to clear all non-`hidden` `input` elements:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type!="hidden"]').val('');
```

Worst case would be that you have to turn this one line of code into a couple of lines of code to identify the elements you want.  But as long as there's some jQuery-selectable pattern to identify the ones you want, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Good answer, but you'll need to escape the `"` to use in-line with `onclick=""`

Comment: @SetSailMedia: Fair point, though I'd argue that a more ideal approach would be to separate the functionality from the markup in the first place so quoting problems simply go away.

Comment: Yeah I think I have to escape those for what I see in my IDE, is marking those as a syntax error.

Comment: @SaulOrtega: Maybe something like this: `.find('input[type!=\'hidden\']')`  That way it's not using double-quotes at all so it shouldn't interfere with the HTML attribute.  But, honestly, this is a significant reason why code and markup (or any code of different languages) should be kept separate.  One language treats the other as simply a string, and the quoting of that string affects the code it contains.

Comment: This is a great solution as well as kiranvj and I would like to mark it as the best but unfortunately I have to mark only one and the other one worked for Cancel and Save buttons. Thanks man.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I just noticed that this doesn't clear dropdown selectors. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @SaulOrtega: Essentially the same principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445492/how-to-reset-a-select-box-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();$(this).closest('form').find('input').val('');$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close')">Add</a>
```

For this:

```
 <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();$(this).closest('form').find('input[type!=\'hidden\']').val('');$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close')">Add</a>
```

So that you are selecting just those `input` elements with `type` not equal to `hidden`.