# How can I reset dropdowns in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I found this post in [how to reset dropdowns in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445492/how-to-reset-a-select-box-using-jquery), which works great but when I select jquery mobile doesn't work anymore. This is my jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/684/

```
<form>
    <select id="name" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select id="name2" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="$('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Any ideas in how to accomplish this?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/685/ let me know if it works for you.

Comment: did my answer work for you @SaulOrtega??

Comment: @Sushil Thank you for your answer, I'm fixing another bug in my code and then I'll get back to your code.

Comment: sure. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is set the value of the `dropdown` to `''`

Try this

```
$('#name2').change(function(){
    $('#name').val('').selectmenu('refresh');
});


$('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').val('').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Here's a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/685/).

Comment: Do you know by any chance how can I reset many of those dropdowns at once? For example in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/686/ when I select the dropdown1 to something else all the other dropdowns would reset.

Comment: instead of using `id` you can use the `class`

Comment: its the same fiddle.. did you change anything?

Comment: yeah you defined the dropdowns with the classes correctly but the dropdowns are not refreshing. you need to do the following`$('.testing').selectmenu();
$('.testing').selectmenu('refresh', true);`.

Comment: yeah i saw this issue. m trying to work on a fix for it

Comment: oh. i thought changing it was easy but its behaving weird.