# How to unselect options in select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my HTML. I have given multiple `option` elements in the `select` tag.

```
<select class="car" multiple size="3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I am able to multi-select by holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. I am able to retrieve the selected values using the following jQuery

```
$.each($(".car option:selected"), function() {
    countries.push($(this).val());
});
```

How can I unselect the value using jQuery? The selected value will be highlighted as shown:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$(".car option:selected").prop('selected' , false)`

Comment: Also note you can make the array of values using `map()` much more simply: `var countries = $(".car option:selected").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the first option on a select box using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445492/how-to-set-the-first-option-on-a-select-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Under what event do you want to unselect the options? It's not clear what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `selected` property to `false`: `$(selector).prop('selected', false)`.

I have added a button and attached a click event to be able to demonstrate.

```js
var countries = [];

function unselect() {
    $.each($(".car option:selected"), function () {
        countries.push($(this).val());
        $(this).prop('selected', false); // <-- HERE
    });
}

$("#unselect").click(unselect);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="car" multiple size="3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="unselect" id="unselect" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$('.car').val([]);` for unselect all options in multi-select dropdown.

> For multi select value you can pass empty array for unselect all
>   options.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select").click(function(){
    var values= [];
    $(".car > option").each(function(){
     values.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    $('.car').val(values);
  });
  
  $("#unselect").click(function(){
    $('.car').val([]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select class="car" multiple size="3">
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <button id="select">Select All</button>
  <button id="unselect">Unselect All</button>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You using select2 use trigger

```
 $("#category_select option:selected").prop("selected", false);
     $("#category_select").trigger('change');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).